# Should I scale data for a regression tree, when the determinant covers a large range?

Tags: regression, cart

I am composing a regression tree to determine corporate dividends with dividends as the determinant and 13 predictor variables. To check the accuracy of the tree I am using RMSE values computed using a random sample set. The problem is my RMSE values are **huge** since the range of dividends (the determinant) is so large.

I was wondering if I should scale the determinant or maybe all of the input data? If I scale the data I get a smaller RMSE but the tree is difficult to read since it has scaled values. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Scaling the variables doesn't change the amount of error, it just changes units. Regression trees are, I am fairly sure, insensitive to monotonic transformations of the predicted variable, so you will get the same result.

Comment: You can be almost sure :)